# .NET Core 6.0: how to add 1 to a primary key value and add this to the database

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have the following function in the generic repository which get the max number of de primary key column. I want to change this this to add 1 to max number and add this value to the primary key and insert the record in the database. How can I do that?

```
public async Task<int> GetMaxPK(Expression<Func<T, int?>> columnSelector)
{
    try
    {
        int maxNumber = await _context.Set<T>().MaxAsync(columnSelector) ?? 0;
        return (int)maxNumber;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Error(ex.Message)
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Calling this function as (`Nr_afspraak` is the primary key):

```
int maxId = await GetMaxPK(afspraak => (int?)afspraak.Nr_Afspraak);
```

Comment: Almost always, this is the wrong thing to do. What happens if two calls to this method are made at the same time? They'll both compute the same max, both add 1 to it, then both insert a new row with the same ID value. Let the *database* take care of assigning numbers using built in functionality such as `IDENTITY` in SQL Server.

Comment: I agree with you. But this is an existing database. I'm thinking of creating a lock and then insert the record and the release the lock. BTW the database is pervasive (Zen).